# Can't print line after looping through scanner input - Java

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

Why does this not print 'done'?

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println(s.nextInt());

    }

    System.out.println("done");

}

}
```

It prints the input just fine, but doesn't print the word done.

***EDIT***  if I input integers separated by space in the console and then hit enter, it prints all the integers I entered on a separate line, but it just doesn't print the word done after all that

***EDIT***

this works… but seems not very elegant

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int temp;

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        temp = s.nextInt();

        if (temp != -99) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        } else {
            break;
        }

    } 



    System.out.println("done");

}

}
```

Comment: Did the input stream ever end? (Ctrl-D on Linux, Ctrl-Z then Enter on Windows)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If the scanner hasNext() but it's empty, shouldn't it keep printing 0?

Comment: It will wait until you type something. hasNext would return false if you were reading from a file and you got to the end of the file, or you were reading from a network connection and the server closed the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is that Scanner is blocking on the input stream where there are no characters, and is just waiting for more.  To signal the end of the stream, the 'end of stream' character has to be sent.  That is ctrl-d on linux.

From the documentation of java.util.Scanner (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
Both hasNext 
and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method 
blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.
```

For example, from a linux command prompt

```
> javac Main.java
> java Main
> 810
810
> 22
22
> foo
java.util.InputMismatchException
> java Main
> 1
1
> ctrl-D
done
```

Another way to test this is to echo a line or cat a file into your program:

```
> echo 2 | java Main
2
done
```

EDIT:

Given the desired outcome described in the comments below; Give the following a try, it will read in only one line.  Parse the space separated ints out, echo them one per line and then print done.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 */
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String str = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(str);

        while (s.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println(s.nextInt());

        }

        System.out.println("done");

    }

}
```

EDIT EDIT: Cleaned up the answer and worked in information from the comments.

Comment: so if i enter the input integers and then hit enter, it prints the integers but no 'done'… then if i press ctrl-d, it prints 'done'… but i need this to happen after i hit enter after entering the last integer

Comment: Do you need this behaviour while typing the input, or can you pipe it in from another file?    What platform are you running, linux, windows, osx?

Comment: when i run the program, i need to be able to enter the integers separated by spaces, then hit enter and have it run everything… can't hit ctrl-d or anything… hitting enter should resume the program through completion

Comment: So am I right in understanding that you want to read a single line of input, process that line and then exit?

Comment: that second edit also seems crummy because then I can't have -99 (or whatever) in my input set

Comment: I've added an edit which I believe does what you need above.  There are of course several ways to do it.

Comment: Chris K -  Yes.  I want to be able to input an unknown amount of ints and then read them and then continue the program… eventually these ints will be put into an array and have logic run on them, but for now I'm just trying to get it to read them and then continue the program

Comment: fyi a short(ish) way to get them into an array is:   

        String[] words = str.split( " " );

Comment: convince me that a buffered reader is the way to go… seems like a long way around the block…  i'm gonna look and see if there is a way to check the type of s.next() and therefore I could enter the input integers and then at the end, enter a char (like 'x').. then put an && operator in the while condition

Comment: You are in control of the requirements, if you prefer entering an x at the end then go for it.  I am merely answering your immediate technical questions.   Unfortunately System.in does not offer a readLine style function, so the alternatives are to use something like BufferedReader, adapt your need, follow linux convention (pipes) or roll your own.

Comment: that's a reasonable persuasion,… it definitely works